# KMM iOS mismatch type ChallengeHandler

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor-client

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is ChallengeHandler /* = (NSURLSession, NSURLSessionTask, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition /* = Long */, NSURLCredential?) -> Unit) -> Unit */ but ChallengeHandler /* = (NSURLSession, NSURLSessionTask, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition /* = Int */, NSURLCredential?) -> Unit) -> Unit */ was expected
```

Basically above error logs happen when migrate to latest client `ktor 2.0.3` and using kotlin `1.7.10`.

Is this a bug from ktor? how can we deal with this issue? should we just postponed update latest ktor until this issue fixed?

I think `platform.darwin.NSInteger` is recognized as Long, thus it got mismatch.
when you search inside `NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition` this is `platform.darwin.NSInteger` but somehow IDE recognized as `Long` not `Int`, so I guess this is a bug?
Run the build also failure by same error above

Can't do anything. tried to create extension to use `Int`, still same..
Tried to cast manually to Int also still error.

Can't build too because of this error.

Anyone have solutions?

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project?

Comment: @vanyochek i am sorry, it is private project, i couldn't share it due to client security rule.. but i could share a chunk of code related to that.. is that okay? if yes, what part would you like to see?

Comment: The `ChallengeHandler` code and the code where TYPE_MISMATCH happens.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
This can actually compiles just fine on native iOS. Should just ignore the error and provide an explanation in the comments section.